# error in result while doing large mathematical operations in C

Tags: c

I have used long long result; to store the result of 150 to power 53 but still it is giving -8 result in C.
I dont know what to use to store such large values in C.

Comment: A bignum lib like https://gmplib.org/

Comment: This was the answer to "I dont know what to use to store such large values in C.". The built-in var types in your CPU can´t store such large numbers (choice of programming language doesn´t matter). You need an array, and every math. operation like addition has to be defined by yourself. That´s where GMP is helping.

Comment: Do you really need to store that large a number while maintaining the accuracy of the less significant digits?  If not, consider using the `double` type.

Comment: 150**53 is 2.151973e+115. You would need approximately 385 bits to store that as an integer. Why do you need it to stay as an integer?

Comment: actually, its exactly 383.12739059628168649130202355511 - hence 384 bits :-)

Comment: 7^((7*log(2)+log(3))/log(7))

Comment: @specializt: I am a better nit-picker: It's not a fraction, so you cannot give it exactly that way.

Comment: yes you can : its called "shannon" - the amount of information of a message. It can be a fraction - if you want to have the REAL amount of information (bits) you simply need to CEIL the result of this calculation : log_n(150^53) / log_n(2), even easier : log_2(150^53)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer representation of 150 to the power 53 would require exactly 384 bits.  The width of `long long` -- if it's even supported -- could vary, but 128 bits is common, and I would be surprised to see it longer than 256 bits.

You can represent the value using some variety of bignum library (in which case you would also need to use that library to manipulate it).  Alternatively, you could store it as a `double`.  A `double` can represent numbers of that magnitude, but they have limited precision.  For many purposes they are entirely sufficient.

Comment: I doubt a `double` can represent that number exactly. The mantissa is unlikely to be big enough to store 75**53, neccessary for binary floating-point.